# Python printing lists with column headers

Tags: list

So I have a nested list containing these values

```
#[[Mark, 10, Orange],
#[Fred, 15, Red],
#[Gary, 12, Blue],
#[Ned, 21, Yellow]]
```

You can see that the file is laid out so you have (name, age, favcolour)
I want to make it so I can display each column with its corresponding header 
E.G

```
Name|Age|Favourite colour
Mark|10 |Orange
Fred|15 |Red
Gary|12 |Blue
Ned |21 |Yellow
```

Thank You!

Comment: can you show the actual list definition? To see if there nested lists or just a strings

Comment: It's as a nested list

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function:

```
l = [['Mark', 10, 'Orange'],['Fred', 15, 'Red'],['Gary', 12, 'Blue'],['Ned', 21, 'Yellow']]
f = '{:<10}|{:<3}|{:<15}'   # format

# header(`Name` column has some gap as there could be long names, like "Cristopher")
print('Name      |Age|Favourite colour') 

for i in l:
    print(f.format(*i))
```

The output:

```
Name      |Age|Favourite colour
Mark      |10 |Orange         
Fred      |15 |Red            
Gary      |12 |Blue           
Ned       |21 |Yellow
```